# Determine if a VirtualKey is a modifier key?

Tags: keyboard, uwp

In my UWP app, I detect a keypress by observing the KeyDown event. That gives me a VirtualKey. But how can I tell whether or not the key is a modifier key?

Comment: You are asking about what you believe to be part of your solution. What problem are you trying to solve? More often than not, when someone asks for modifiers in a `KeyDown` event handler, they have already opted for the wrong solution.

Comment: I want to detect and respond to keypresses. In the case of modifier keys, I don't want to respond at all. In the case of text keys, I can get the text by subscribing to CharacterReceived.  Other keypresses I can't capture that way, so I am subscribing also to KeyDown. There, I do various things with specific keys -- not including modifiers. So I didn't end using the info from here, BUT I do end up using the array, as in KeyDown, I handle it differently depending on what modifiers are pressed.

Comment: To add a little more context -- this is a Windows front end for an app that already exists on other platforms. So it has a multitude of different handlers for various keypresses. The front end's job is simply to figure out what has been pressed, and to use some kind of sane mapping to convert it to the core's KeyPress type.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I have. I'm sure it's incomplete, and it's definitely not future-proof. I'm hoping there is a better answer. In the meantime, others are invited to add keys I missed.

```
public static VirtualKey[] ModifierKeys =
{
  VirtualKey.Shift,
  VirtualKey.LeftShift,
  VirtualKey.RightShift,
  VirtualKey.LeftWindows,
  VirtualKey.RightWindows,
  VirtualKey.Menu,    // aka alt
  VirtualKey.Control,
  VirtualKey.LeftControl,
  VirtualKey.RightControl,
  VirtualKey.CapitalLock,
  VirtualKey.NumberKeyLock,
  VirtualKey.Insert,
};

public static bool IsModifierKey(this VirtualKey key) {
  bool r = ModifierKeys.Contains(key);
  return r;
}
```